# Initialize Hibernate SessionFactory in a EJB mdb?

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I am trying to deploy an MDB in WAS 8.5. The session Factory is being initialized in ejbCreate method. When I try to deploy the application ejb loads successfully and then it shuts down the Queue Activation and  gives the following exceptions- 
I am not using any framework or MAven for built so all the jars and config files have been added to the classpath as in a Standalone Java Application.

Here are the Hibernate and JAVAEE Jars I am using-

```
antlr-2.7.7
c3p0-0.9.1
commons-collections-3.2.1
commons-logging-api-1.1.3
dom4j-1.6.1
hibernate-c3p0-4.1.5.Final
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final
hibernate-core-4.1.5.Final
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.5.Final
hibernate-envers-4.1.5.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final
javassist-3.15.0GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final
jms-1.1
log4j-1.2.15
MySQL-connector-java-5.1.22
slf4j-api-1.6.1
javaee.jar
javaee-api-6.0
```

Here is the exception stacktrace from system logs

```
EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of  method "onMessage".Exception data: 
          javax.ejb.EJBException: MDB PostConstruct failure; nested exception is: 
          java.lang.Exception: See nested Throwable
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:472)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageDrivenBeanO.initialize(MessageDrivenBeanO.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanOFactory.create(BeanOFactory.java:147)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1238)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1356)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.UncachedActivationStrategy.atActivate 
          (UncachedActivationStrategy.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.Activator.preInvokeActivateBean(Activator.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeActivate(EJSContainer.java:4205)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeMdbActivate(EJSContainer.java:3709)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.beforeDelivery
          (MessageEndpointHandler.java:1449)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invokeMessageEndpointMethod
          (MessageEndpointHandler.java:866)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointHandler.java:832)
    at $Proxy50.beforeDelivery(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.AbstractWorkImpl.run(AbstractWorkImpl.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:608)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
          Caused by: java.lang.Exception: See nested Throwable
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:470)
    ... 15 more
          Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.HibernateException
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:85)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:162)
    at com.hps.superenrollment.ejbmodule.SuperEnrollmentRequestMDB.ejbCreate
          (SuperEnrollmentRequestMDB.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor
          (InterceptorProxy.java:232)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed
          (InvocationContextImpl.java:559)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doLifeCycle  
          (InvocationContextImpl.java:273)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageDrivenBeanO.initialize(MessageDrivenBeanO.java:411)
```

Please help me as I am completely lost on what is going wrong here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NoClassDefFoundError indicates that some Hibernate class is not in your class-path.  Are you sure you have all dependency jars in your classpath (including the jars which are needed at runtime)?

The exception indicating that you should use a PostConstructor method instead of the bean class constructor indicates that you should use the ejbCreate() method.  This is the recommended location to initialise and load dependencies of your MDB as it is called by one single thread of the ejb container and ensures that the MDB has been fully constructed before you execute the configuration in the ejbCreate().  It is somewhat similar to the init method in a servlet which is also guaranteed to be called single threaded by the servlet container.

Comment: That might be a good thing to do.  Indeed the exceptions thrown at hibernate initialisation are a bit tricky.  They can relate to any sort of configuration exception.  I would double check the config and load it with a minimum setting and mapping if possible to diminish your error scope.

Comment: Filip, Thanks for your input. My hibernate.cfg.xml is already bare minimum with only db details , userid/password, and the mapping class. I will try using ejbCreate to initialize session factory and will let you know how it went !

Comment: Hi Filip, Now that I am using ejbCreate for initialising sessionFactory ....I am getting a lot of classnotfound exception for Hibernate. Since I am not using Maven for build how do I add the Hibernate jars to classpath to resolve the Classnotfound Exceptions which are happening at runtime since the jars are not getting exported with the EAR file. Please suggest as I have been looking at this for 2 straight days with no resolution !

Comment: It all depends on how you structured your project.  Check the manifest of your EJB component to see that it references all the required jars from the correct EAR location.  You also might need to check your EJB descriptor to verify the classloading policy.
You can also add the jars (just for debugging reasons) directly into your server classpath to ensure that all classes are loaded directly from the server to exclude any other failures...

Comment: The Manifest of my EJB module has only the manifest version and in the Class-Path entry it has the reference of the EJBClient.jar. The EJBClient.jar does not have anything the Manifest.MF. Please guide me on how should I get this fixed ? Thanks again for you help .